# Working on an Eclipse project (using Builders) in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ant

I've recently been tasked with working on an existing eclipse project that makes use of Builders to run Ant tasks under given conditions. I've never heard of Builders before yesterday, and I'm having difficulties getting the project to work in IntelliJ.

First of all, I would like to know if there is a way I can effectively trick Ant into running from a different base directory than what it already does. Consider the following screenshot from Eclipse:

[image]

Here, project A is running an Ant task in a local build file that extends a build file from project B. As you can see from the Base Directory setting, it is different from that of A. When I try to run the task from this build file in IntelliJ, I get build errors because certain directories do not exist in the folder for project A -- they are located in project B.

Secondly, this Builder is set to trigger on Manual Build and Auto Build, but my understanding is that this only triggers if the project the builder is attached to gets built. As far as I can tell, in IntelliJ, I can set an Ant task to trigger before or after a build, but it seems like this will be for the whole project, instead of just the relevant module that represents this Eclipse project. Is there a way I can make it only apply to a given module, or will I have to trigger it for changes to all modules?